# ajax sucess response data to load a div using if condition

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

After for getting ajax response loading a div in the div i have radio button fields how should i write a condition inside jquery.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "miscellaneous_fetch.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    transaction_id: transaction_id
  },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    var html = '';
    html += '<div class="col-md-1"></div><div class="col-md-3"><fieldset><h5 align="left"><b>Due-Date:</b></h5><div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="due_date" value="none"  checked>None</label></div><div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="due_date" value="header" >Header</label></div><div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="due_date" value="body">Body</label></div></fieldset></div></div><br>';
    $('.miscellaneous_body').append(html);
  }
```

i want to write if condition to check with ajax response data where checked or not if checked we have to put checked tag to that field.

Comment: Are you able to provide the PHP code on the server-side so that we know what response you're getting?

Comment: "we have to put checked tag to that field" - what do you mean?

Comment: what did you got response from `server` does it return radio button value which you need to checked?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

```
$.ajax({
                  url: "miscellaneous_fetch.php",
                  method: "POST",
                  data: {
                    transaction_id: transaction_id
                  },
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                 if(data == 'Your Condition'){
                 //Your CODE
                 }else{
                 //Your CODE
                  }
            }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for replay,i need inside if condition code like.. var html = '';
html += '<div class="col-md-1"></div><div class="col-md-3"><fieldset><h5 align="left"><b>Due-Date:</b></h5><div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="due_date" value="none"  if(data.value == 1){ checked }>None</label></div>'<div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="due_date" value="header" if(data.value == 1){ checked }>Header';              if(data.value ==1){checked} like this i want to check but jquery want take that code is their any solution using php also usfull